# Run a script with arguments using crontab

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh, cron

I know this may have been answered earlier in various posts, but I've not been able to make this run myself.

I have a bash script *(service.sh)* that I would like to run every minute. It needs an argument to be passed (*start* in this case).

Using another script *(test.sh)* I am scheduling the cron expression for the above script:

```
echo "* * * * * /opt/service.sh start" > /opt/cronForSecops
crontab /opt/cronForSecops
```

I can see by using *crontab -l* that this is being set correctly as:

```
* * * * * /opt/service.sh start
```

However, the *service.sh* does not run, and I see no logs/files being created (which the *service.sh* file is supposed to do, when I run it normally).

Can anybody please guide me on where I am going wrong?

Comment: Does service.sh have execute permissions? Is the crontab configured for the correct user, and does that user have execute permissions?

Comment: Take a look at the [crontab tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) for steps to debug and report back with your findings

Comment: Also make sure that the user with the crontab job actually have permissions to run the bash script you have in /opt. A tip might be to look in the /var/log/syslog for permission denied-ish errors, if that's not something you've already done, referring to the "..and I see no logs/files being created..".

Comment: In addition to what others have mentioned, you might want to double check the PATH variable within the script.  It may be failing to find the programs you've asked it to run.
Lastly, some versions of cron have a bug where the final entry gets ignored if it doesn't end with a newline.  Make sure you add an extra newline at the end of your crontab just to be sure.

Comment: service.sh has permissions, and crontab is being configured for the same user (non-root). I am able to run the service.sh using the same user.

Comment: I also tried @GigaWatt 's comment, but I don't see the script being executed anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same issue where I using the following crontab:

```
0 23 * * * sudo -u myname /home/myname/bin/buildme.sh -f >> /home/myname/log.txt
```

And inside the bash script I was using this to get the -f option:

```
while getopts ":f" opt; do
    case $opt in
        f)
            force_full=1
            ;;
        \?)
            echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
            ;;
    esac
done
```

So I noticed that the option wasn't being honored when I ran this through cron for some reason.  Well, adding /bin/bash to the cronjob fixed it right up.  The new crontab is:

```
0 23 * * * sudo -u myname /bin/bash /home/myname/bin/buildme.sh -f >> /home/myname/log.txt
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a simple wrapper script called `/opt/start-service.sh` with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh
/opt/service.sh start
```

and make sure it's executable then use

```
* * * * * /opt/start-service.sh
```

as the crontab entry

Comment: How would this fix the issue?

Comment: @GigaWatt is the issue not that arguments to ````service.sh```` get ignored?